# How can I convert an integer variable in PLSQL to pass to a boolean procedure parameter?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing unit tests for an existing procedure which has boolean parameters. As the tests run, they will store the associated parameter values in a table. I want to use variables for setting the parameter columns in the table and to pass to the procedure. Is there a way to go from an integer (what I'll set in my table) to the procedure (which requires boolean values)?

I've tried passing 1/0 values and the strings "TRUE" and "FALSE" to the procedure. I've tried making my table use a boolean datatype for the relevant columns. I've tried CASTing. I've tried using a SELECT INTO with CASE statement to set a different boolean-type variable based on the value of the integer-type variable.

```sql
CREATE TABLE UNIT_TEST_RESULTS (
case VARCHAR2(50)
,includeLines NUMBER(1) --this will hold the value of i_includeLines below
,result VARCHAR2(4)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE X_UNIT_TEST AS
i_includeLines NUMBER(1)
BEGIN
i_includeLines:=0;
X_THING_TO_TEST(includeLinesBool=>i_includeLines);

/*...analyze output...*/

INSERT INTO UNIT_TEST_RESULTS(case,includeLines,result)
VALUES ('test',i_includeLines,'fail'); COMMIT;

END X_UNIT_TEST;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably do something like

```
  i_includeLines NUMBER(1)
  b_includeLines boolean;
BEGIN
  i_includeLines:=0;
  b_includeLines := (case i_includeLines when 1 then true else false end);
  X_THING_TO_TEST(includeLinesBool=>b_includeLines);
```

or

```
  b_includeLines boolean;
  i_includeLines integer;
BEGIN
  b_includeLines:= false;
  X_THING_TO_TEST(includeLinesBool=>b_includeLines);

  /*...analyze output...*/

  i_includeLines := case when b_includeLines = true then 1 else 0 end;
  INSERT INTO UNIT_TEST_RESULTS(case,includeLines,result)
    VALUES ('test',i_includeLines,'fail'); 
  COMMIT;
```

Obviously, either of these `case` statements could (and should) get encapsulated into a function assuming you are going to call them regularly.

I would suggest that you not use the reserved word `case` for a column name-- that's going to bite you at some point.  I'm also not a fan of the Hungarian notation for variable names but that's more of a religious debate...

Comment: Thanks. I've ended up going with some closer to your first suggestion. I'm not a big fan of the variable name convention either, but that's the standard my company uses, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There's no Boolean in your code so - here's how I understood the question:

You have a procedure which accepts parameter that is Boolean:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (par_bool in boolean)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

You want to call it; there's some *number* variable (`l_int` in my example) and you'd want to convert it to Boolean and pass as such to the `p_test` procedure. Here's how:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_int integer := 1;
  3  begin
  4    p_test(case when l_int = 1 then true else false end);
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit conversion from numbers or strings to Boolean, but a simple true/false expression like `i_includeLines = 1` evaluates to Boolean `true` if `i_includeLines` has the value `1`, so you could call your procedure like this:

```
x_thing_to_test(includeLinesBool => i_includeLines = 1);
```

That will pass `true` if `i_includeLines` is 1, `false` if it is not 1, else `null`.

If you need to treat null as `false` then you'll need a `case`/`coalesce`/`nvl` or similar expression.